# Problemas com o Dev-cpp

Tags: c#, c, c++

Instalei o Dev-Cpp 5.5.1 e ele apresenta um erro assim quando tento compilar:

> "Failed to execute (e o caminho do arquivo)".

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Já tentei a versão 4.9.9.2 e acontece o mesmo erro.

Comment: Cara, o Dev-Cpp é um projeto realmente bem antigo... nem achava que existia mais.

Comment: Isso acontece com todo código que você tenta compilar?

Comment: Em antiguidade devcpp vem logo depois do turbo c++, sai dessa. Será que ainda existem escolas que usam estes dois?...

Comment: @pepper_chico, eu ainda uso o DevCPP não exatamente esta versão, mas sim o wxDevCPP que é essencialmente a mesma IDE com suporte a WxWidgets.

Answer (score 1):

Você provavelmente está usando Windows 32 bits e compilando para Windows 64 bits. Mesmo que o compilador vai rodar em 32 bits, o executável criado não vai funcionar.

Tente selecionar um perfil 32bits em Tools >> Compiler Options. Se não estiver ali, tente o botão 'profile finder' (os dois sinais 'plus' amarelos). Outra alternativa é tentar passar -m32 para o compilador.